# Better expression for "is needed to be highlighted"

Tags: expression-choice

I want to emphasize A and B. So I wrote:
"A and B are needed to be highlighted."

I feel it is not natural. What would be better way in written English?

Comment: could you give some more context. Are we talking about writing or speaking or just the message itself.

Comment: I think this level of question is better suited to [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). @Daebarkee - just replace the clumsy (and grammatically incorrect) *are needed to be* with ***must***.

Comment: Belongs in English Language Learners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sentence is incorrectly structured. You could say `A and B need to be highlighted.` That would make more sense.

Comment: Yes. When _need_ takes an infinitive complement, it can't be passivized.

Comment: Here, A and B are not person. Some actions. Ex. Continuous exercise and money saving are needed to be highlighted. Do you think in this case, still, "need to be highlighted" is correct?

Comment: @Daebarkee: yes

Comment: Or as in the Pittsburgh region, thanks to Scottish immigrants, it's OK to say, "A and B need highlighted"! That wording seems to emphasize the importance of A and B being highlighted, at least in speech. Formal writing is another matter.

Comment: @rhetorician: Really?  That's... ugh... no.